# Running a function on multiple elements using Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, element

I've got some code that I'd like to run on every single checkbox on my page within a table, but I'm not sure of the best way to do this? I've tried something like this but it didn't work :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function whatever (elem) {
        var $elem = elem;
        $elem.val('test');
    }

    $('table tr td :checkbox').(function() {
        whatever($(this));
    }

});
```

Any help would be fantastic, at a bit of a loss with this! Thanks :)

Comment: You can select an answer as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 8):

Use $.each();

```
$.each($('table tr td :checkbox'), function()
    {
       // Code
    });
```

To access the checkbox you are currently working on in the loop, use this.

```
$.each($('table tr td :checkbox'), function()
    {
       $(this).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [$().each()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each).

And by the way, `foo.(bar)` is not valid Javascript syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the info, sorry to be stupid but can you explain where I used the foo.(bar) thing please? Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, it is good you ask :). In the following (copied from your code, rearranged to fit on a single line): `$('table tr td :checkbox').(function() { whatever($(this)); }`. In this case `foo` is `$('...')` and `bar` is `function() { ... }`.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! That's a very handy explanation, as I've often seen 'foo' and 'bar' and didn't realise what they meant until now!

Comment: They are simply placeholders. Instead of having to write a long piece of code to make a point, I used placeholders. They are also used for names of variables or classes when you just want to explain an abstract idea.